# Combine multiple queries into one query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to group by `clientid` and `m.id`. How can I convert these 2 queries into 1 query?

**Query 1**

```
select cs.clientid, count(distinct(m.id)) as cp
into #temp
from call_table cs 
join mem_table m 
on cs.CLIENTID = m.clientid
join activity_table a 
on a.memid = m.id 
where a.activity = 'abc'
group by cs.clientid, m.id
```

**Query 2**

```
select clientid, sum(cp) from #temp
group by ClientId
```

**Update**

More specifically, I am looking to write this query without using a temp table.

Comment: [`UNION ALL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: add union between both queries

Comment: You could put the first query in a subquery of the second. `SELECT clientid, SUM(cp) FROM (SELECT cs.client_id, COUNT(DISTINCT(m.id)) AS cp FROM call_table cs ...) AS subquery GROUP BY clientid`

Comment: @Wodin Thank you. I have updated my question.

Comment: You could use a table variable. It would probably be faster than a temp table

Comment: Out of interest, why are you doing `count(distinct(m.id))` when `m.id` is in your `GROUP BY`? The result of `count(distinct(m.id))` is always going to be 1.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results!

Comment: @JamesAMohler Can you give an example.

Comment: See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group only by clientid

And since no fields from activity_table are selected,  an EXISTS can be used instead.

```
select cs.clientid, count(distinct m.id) as cp
from call_table cs 
join mem_table m on m.clientid = cs.clientid
where exists 
(
    select 1
    from activity_table a 
    where a.memid = m.id 
      and a.activity = 'abc'
)
group by cs.clientid
```

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just write this as:

```
with temp as (
      select cs.clientid, count(distinct m.id) as cp
      from call_table cs join
           mem_table m 
           on cs.CLIENTID = m.clientid join
           activity_table a 
           on a.memid = m.id 
      where a.activity = 'abc'
      group by cs.clientid, m.id 
     )
select clientid, sum(cp)
from temp
group by ClientId;
```

I can't figure out what the logic should really be, but this seems like the simplest way to combine the queries.

I would speculate that you simply want this query:

```
      select cs.clientid, count(distinct m.id) as cp
      from call_table cs join
           mem_table m 
           on cs.CLIENTID = m.clientid join
           activity_table a 
           on a.memid = m.id 
      where a.activity = 'abc'
      group by cs.clientid;
```

That is, remove `m.id` from the `group by`.  And this can in turn be simplified to:

```
      select m.clientid, count(distinct m.id) as cp
      from mem_table m join
           activity_table a 
           on a.memid = m.id 
      where a.activity = 'abc'
      group by cs.clientid;
```

Assuming that `m.id` is unique and non-`NULL`, this can be further simplified to:

```
      select m.clientid, count(*) as cp
      from mem_table m join
           activity_table a 
           on a.memid = m.id 
      where a.activity = 'abc'
      group by cs.clientid;
```